# Order of infinite dimension norms

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I know that
$$\|{f}\|_{L^1(0,L)}\leq\|{f}\|_{L^2(0,L)}\leq\|{f}\|_{\mathscr{C}^1(0,L)}\leq\|{f}\|_{\mathscr{C}^2(0,L)}\leq\|{f}\|_{\mathscr{C}^{\infty}(0,L)}$$

But I don't know where to put in this chain this norm:

$\|{f}\|_{L^{\infty}}=\inf\{C\in\mathbb{R},\left|f(x)\right|\leq{C}\text{ almost everywhere}\}$

Thanks pals.

Comment: Before getting into this, what does $(0,L)$ mean in your notation?

Comment: Means $$\|f\|_{L^2(0,L)}=(\int_{0}^{L}f(t)^2dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

And in the case of continuity means where the function is continous up to the given order.

Comment: I don't understand you first question. The norm you mention act on smooth functions (and are equal for constant functions).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo you are right, fixed

Comment: What do you mean by $\lVert f\rVert_{C^\infty(0,L)}$?

Answer (score 1):

If the norm $\mathcal C^1$ is defined by $\sup_{0<x<L}|f(x)|+\sup_{0<x<L}|f'(x)|$, then we have 
$$\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}\leqslant \sqrt L\lVert f\rVert_{L^{\infty}}\leqslant \sqrt L\lVert f\rVert_{\mathcal C^1}.$$

Comment: How did you see that?
And is also true then
$$\|f\|_{L^p(0,L)}\leq\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq\|f\|_{\mathscr{C}^{0}}$$ for any $p$?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a constant.

Comment: Could you sketch a proof? or is it too long?

Comment: Use the fact that $|f(x)|\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_\infty$, then take the square and integrate.

Comment: but what is $\left|f(x)\right|$ for every $x$?